# Record webcam video with wxPython

Tags: python, opencv, wxpython

can i use video capture function in wxpython button event for recording OpenCV video stream?

Comment: So you got the code from somewhere here on SO, which means you probably don't really understand how it works, and want to apply it to another GUI toolkit. You haven't explained what you need it for, why you want to use wxPython and not Tkinter, or what you've tried so far. In other words, you want SO to do all the work for you?

Comment: Being a beginner in python I have tried something, but i couldn't get a video stream in Tkinter GUI. I came to know it is possible with wxpython  so I am switching over to wxPython, even i have modified some codes by myself but the prob is can't record video stream that i got.